# Exception not being caught in try-catch

Tags: wpf, vb.net, exception, try-catch

I have a try-catch around a line of code that can generate an exception, however, the catch is not catching it. I still get an unhandled exception. Why is this?

In this example, I already have an image located at C:\temp\defect.bmp, when I try to save an image with the same path I get a System.IO.IOException on the dim imageStream line of code because I incorrectly used CreateNew mode, so this should throw an exception, but why doesn't the Catch ex as Exception catch it?

```vb
Class MainWindow

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim image As New WpfImage("C:\TEMP\defect.bmp")

        Try
            Dim imageStream As New IO.FileStream("C:\TEMP\defect.bmp", IO.FileMode.CreateNew)

            image.Save(imageStream, ImageFormat.BMP)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("This exception has been caught: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Just to make sure: Does the exception not come from `New WpfImage("C:\TEMP\defect.bmp")`?

Comment: And what is WpfImage? It's not part of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I was using an API (for WPFImage) that had its own Exception class. I had an import at the top of the file for its namespace, so in the my try-catch, it wasn't a System.Exception, it was the Exception in the API's namespace. I am rather disappointed in the company that made the API for having their own Exception class of the same name.

I changed my code to:
Catch ex as System.Exception

Then it worked and caught exceptions correctly.

Comment: Why are you using such a third-party library at all? Loading and saving images in different formats can easily be done with WPF only.

Comment: Its a machine vision software package that I started using for work.

Comment: In my opinion, that's a poor design to re-use the name `Exception`, even when it's in a namespace, because exactly the same issue that you observed is likely to ensue.  I'd suggest raising an issue about it with the package maintainers.